# How to use store procedures in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4, stored-procedures, tiny-tds

I am using ActiveRecord SQLServer Adapter and I am trying to use a store procedure called "SPAD_ReporteComisiones", searching the web I found [this](https://nasir.wordpress.com/2007/12/03/stored-procedures-and-rails/) tutorial, but at the time of reloading it shows me the following error

```
uninitialized constant StoredProceduresController::DbStoredProcedure
```

I have created a model called DbStoredProcedure:

```
class DbStoredProcedure < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.fetch_db_records(SPAD_ReporteComisiones)
    connection.select_all(SPAD_ReporteComisiones)
  end

end
```

and this is my index action:

```
  def index
    @orders = DbStoredProcedure.fetch_records("exec SPAD_ReporteComisiones '164','2014/06/28','2014/06/29','208'")
  end
```

How could I run that stored? I need to load all the data to render in the index view

Comment: Please refer, [use of stored procedures in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517388/stored-procedures-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stored procedures in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517388/stored-procedures-in-ruby-on-rails)