# Rails - Large database queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .net, ruby, database, postgresql

Let's say I need to implement a search algorithm for a product catalog database. This would include multiple joins across the products table, manufacturers table, inventory table, etc. etc.

In .NET / MSSQL, I would isolate such logic in a DB stored procedure, then write a wrapper method in my data access layer of my .NET app to simply call this stored procedure.

How does something like this work in RoR? From my basic understanding, RoR uses its ORM by default. Does this mean, I have to move my search logic into the application layer, and write it using its ORM? The SQL stored proc is pretty intense... For performance, it needs to be in the stored procedure.

How does this work in RoR?

Edit: From the first two responses, I gather that ActiveRecord is the way to do things in Ruby. Does this mean that applications that require large complex queries with lots of joins, filtering and even dynamic SQL can (should) be re-written using ActiveRecord classes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to run raw SQL statements in Rails, using the [execute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-execute) method on a `connection` object, by doing so you will forfeit all the benefits of ActiveRecord. If you still want to go down this path, you can use it like so:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("call stored_procedure_name")
```

---

Another option to explore might be to create a "query object" to encapsulate your query logic. Inside, you could still use ActiveRecord query methods. ActiveRecord has become fairly proficient in optimizing your SQL queries, and there is still some manual tweaking you could do.

Below is a simple scaffoold for such an object:

```
# app/queries/search_products.rb

class SearchProducts
  def initialize(params)
    @search = search
  end

  def call
    Product.where(...) # Plus additional search logic
  end
end
```

---

The third option would be to go with something like [elasticsearch-rails](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails) or [sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot). This will require some additional setup time and added complexity, but might pay off down the line, if your search requirements change.

Comment: Thanks @Drenmi. So if ActiveRecord is the way to do this, how do developers implement crazy large and complex search algorithms in rails? Is it all done via the ActiveRecord classes?

Comment: In my experience, for large and complex search, most developers use third party services or gems. There are a lot of pitfalls to rolling your own. Even getting case insensitive indexes in Postgres can be a bit confusing. I forgot to mention a gem called Sunspot in my answer, but I've added it in an edit. You can check it out to see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure is one of way to make the apps can be faster sometimes but it will need high costs and time to debug code for developer. Rails is using `ActiveRecord` ORM so if you want to use stored procedure that will lead to the main function ActiveRecord unused well.

There are some explains about rails
[stored-procedures-in-ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517388/stored-procedures-in-ruby-on-rails) and [using stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953001/using-stored-procedures-in-rails)

Comment: Thanks. Same question here... What is your recommended approach to large/complex queries involving many joins, including dynamic SQL? Would one typically refactor into a suitable series of commands using ActiveRecord?

Comment: Okay, I will share what I've done when I had complex queries . Basically Rails includes to execute sql query with `find_by_sql` so you just copy your sql and put inside of this method. It's very helpful for me to not change my sql code into `ActiveRecord` style. This is how find_by_sql can execute SQL syntax http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class.